# why does my Action event is not being triggered?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

I am trying to build a simple notepad. But for some reason my action event is not being triggered after clicking on the *New* menu item. The code given below should call a *newFile()* method, when user click on *New* menu item.

```
public class MainUi implements ActionListener{
    
    //all the variables
    public JFrame window;
    public JTextArea textArea;
    public JScrollPane scrollPane;
    public JMenuBar menuBar;
    public JMenu menuFile, menuEdit, menuFormat;
    public JMenuItem fNew, fOpen, fSave, fSaveAs, fExit;
    
    //creating instance of all the functional class
    File_functions file = new File_functions(this);
    
    //Constructor to build the ui
    public MainUi() {
        createWindow();
        createMenuBar();
        addFileMenu();
        createTextArea();
        
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainUi();
    }
    //menu bar
        public void createMenuBar() {
            menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            
            //add file to the menu
            menuFile = new JMenu("File");
            menuBar.add(menuFile);
        }
        
        //all the file menu
        public void addFileMenu() {
            fNew = new JMenuItem("New");
            menuFile.add(fNew);
            menuFile.addActionListener(this);
            menuFile.setActionCommand("New");
        }

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        System.out.print(command);
        switch (command) {
            case "New": file.newFile();  break;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error showing in console neither inside another class *(File_function)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        fNew = new JMenuItem("New");
        menuFile.add(fNew);
        menuFile.addActionListener(this);
```

The ActionListener needs to be added to the JMenuItem:

```
        fNew = new JMenuItem("New");
        menuFile.add(fNew);
        //menuFile.addActionListener(this);
        fNew.addActionListener(this);
```

Note, there is no need to set the action command. It will default to the text of the menu item.